# Using Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean, logical-operators

What is the best way to split the array so that I can only iterate over negative values, then positive values and then zero? for instance:

```
x= [[-20., -15., -10.,  -5.,   0.,   5.,  10.,  15.,  20.]]
y= [[-20., -15., -10.,  -5.,   0.,   5.,  10.,  15.,  20.]]
Q1=8
Q2 =12

    if y>0.0 and x -y>=-Q1:
        return 'sum function'
    elif y<0.0 and x -y>=-Q2:
        return 'sum function'
    elif y==0.0 and x >=-Q1:
        return 'sum function'
    return 0.0
```

I'm getting the Error-type: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: You have nested lists. Is it nessesary?

Comment: yes @Dmitry, as this is the form I'm getting when printing y and x in my main code. I just wanted to keep it like the form it is generating in my main code

Comment: @Dmitry, in my main code, when printing y I'm getting something like y= `[[-200.         -197.98994975 -195.9798995  ...,  195.9798995   197.98994975
   200.        ]]`. That is why I kept my question in the same form.

Comment: I would suggest the use of `filter`

Comment: What is the expected output?  An array or a value?

Comment: `[el for el in y[0] if el > 0.0]`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, I'm relatively new to python. How does filter work? the functions I'm trying to evaluate are of the forms for instance `Positive_RG = norm.pdf(x-y+Q1, mu, sigma)`

Comment: @waterboy5281 there are two comparing in each statement. which takes values from both x and y. how do I execute the second one? for instance `elem1 in y and elem2 in x` using your approach?

Comment: It depends on how you want to compare the arrays `x` and `y`. I think we need more information to fully understand your needs.

Comment: For example, `x-y >= -Q1` ... what exactly are you trying to evaluate here?

Comment: @waterboy5281, many thanks for your question. y is a row vector and x are columns vectors of a matrix. hence x varies in each iteration. for instance in one iteration I select. `y= [[-200.         -197.98994975 -195.9798995  ...,  195.9798995   197.98994975
   200.        ]]` and x= [[ -1.1332999 ]
 [ -1.55910508]
 [ -0.69795703]
 ..., 
 [-14.56076754]
 [-14.49447848]
 [-14.73089473]]. I want to compare y[i] and x[i] in each iteration

Comment: @waterboy5281, this is a small part of my code from a previous question. just to show how it looks like. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42545861/if-y0-0-and-x-y-q1-valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-o

Comment: @Eric, I had a look at your code and I'm not sure of what you want. Is it a): all elements of x and y arrays satisfy (y>0 and x-y>Q1) at the same time, (or one of the other two conditions), and you want to execute a function on the whole array when the condition is satisfied, or b): you want to execute a function on the pairs that satisfy the first condition, another function on the pairs that satisfy the second condition,... (or c): something else?)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, I have since amended that small code as suggested by some members here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554270/q2-attributeerror-builtin-function-or-method-object-has-no-attribute-size. could you possibly have a look at this question instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this is what you want, but you haven't specified your output.

```
def sum_function(x,y):
    return x[:, None] + y[None, :]   # or however you want to add them, broadcasted to 2D

def myFilter(x,y):
    x, y = x.squeeze(), y.squeeze()
    out=np.zeros((x.size,y.size))
    xyDiff = x[:, None] - y[None, :]
    out=np.where(np.bitwise_and(y[None, :] => 0.0, xyDiff >= -Q1), sum_function(x, y), out) # unless the sum functions are different
    out=np.where(np.bitwise_and(y[None, :] < 0.0, xyDiff >= -Q2), sum_function(x, y), out)
    return out
```

Comment: Hello @daniel Forsman. Thanks. I have been struggling with this for the past day. I'm relatively new to python. Could you possibly look at how my function is sctructured in this link from a previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42545861/if-y0-0-and-x-y-q1-valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-o

Comment: That still doesn't tell me what you want.  You don't even call the function in the code there.  Try running a few lines at a time and understanding what you are creating, because it really seems like you wrote a pile of code without testing at any step and are just trying to fix the explicit errors.  That will hardly ever give you the output you want.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, I will do.

Comment: Hello again daniel @Daniel Forsman. I have amended the code as you suggested but I'm still getting the error 
  line 57, in myFilter
    out=np.zeros((x.size,y.size))

AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'size'. do you know why? here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554270/q2-attributeerror-builtin-function-or-method-object-has-no-attribute-size

Comment: Are x and y nested lists instead of numpy arrays?

Comment: by nested array, do you mean for instance as this print shows y [[-200.         -197.98994975 -195.9798995  ...,  195.9798995   197.98994975
   200.        ]]? if yes then yes they are nested array. sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: `squeeze` is a function, and i forgot the parentheses.  should be `.squeeze()`

Answer (score 2):

You can just use logical indexing to split an array into positive, negative and zeroes:

```
import numpy

x = numpy.array([-20., -15., -10.,  -5.,   0.,   5.,  10.,  15.,  20.])
y = numpy.array([-20., -15., -10.,  -5.,   0.,   5.,  10.,  15.,  20.])
Q1 = 8
Q2 = 12

positives = x[x > 0]
negatives = x[x < 0]
zeroes = x[x == 0]
```

And you can use `numpy.logical_and` to do your comparison expressions on both arrays at once, always comparing the two values at the same position:

```
print y[numpy.logical_and(y > 0.0, x - y >= -Q1)]
print y[numpy.logical_and(y < 0.0, x - y >= -Q2)]
print y[numpy.logical_and(y == 0.0, x >= -Q1)]
```

Comment: `numpy.logical_and(y > 0.0, x - y >= -Q1)` returns an array, is still can't be casted to boolean without using `all` or `any`

Comment: Yes, it returns a boolean array for all elements where this condition is true. Maybe I misunderstood what OP wanted it to return...

Comment: As I understand it, he wants to use it in its condition: `if (......)`. He gets an error because `and` can't do anything with the arrays, as they can't be casted to booleans... At least with Python3. With Python 2, y>0.0   evaluates to `True` for any  list. Python 3 refuses to compare a list and a float.

Comment: Well, reading the question again, *I* misunderstood what he meant to do...

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, still trying to get it to work. Could you possibly see a part of my code in a previous post so that you can see what I meant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42545861/if-y0-0-and-x-y-q1-valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-o

Comment: `numpy.logical_and(y > 0.0, x - y >= -Q1)` can be more concisely spelt `(y > 0.0) & (x - y >= -Q1)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use numpy and array as filters:

```
from numpy import array
x = array([-10, 5, -5, 10, 0, 0])
for u in x[x < 0]:
   print(u)
for u in x[x > 0]:
   print(u)
for u in x[x == 0]:
   print(0)
```

The advantage of using numpy is that it will provide for all you numerical needs.

Or you could use a generator:

```
x = [-10, 5, -5, 10, 0, 0]
gen_x_pos = (u for u in x if u > 0)
for u in gen_x_pos:
    print(u)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your arrays are numpy arrays.

```
y=np.array([[-20., -15., -10.,  -5.,   0.,   5.,  10.,  15.,  20.]])
x= np.array( [[-20., -15., -10.,  -5.,   0.,   5.,  10.,  15.,  20.]])
Q1=8
Q2 =12

print(y>0.0)
# [[False False False False False  True  True  True  True]]
print(x-y > -Q1)
#[[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]]
```

`y>0 and x-y >= -Q1` gives an error: you are using Python's `and` - that operates on two booleans - between two arrays.
So Python tries to cast your arrays to booleans, but doesn't know what you mean.
Is an array `True` if `all` of its elements are `True`, or if `any` of them is `True`?
If you mean 'all of them must be True', you can do :

```
print(all(y>0.0))
# False
print(all(x-y > -Q1))
# True

print(all(y>0.0) and all(x-y > -Q1))
# False
```

You could also make a logical `and` element by element on your tables before you use `all` or `any`:

```
print(all((y>0.0) & (x-y > -Q1)))
# False
```

If you want to execute a function for the (x,y) pairs that satisfy both conditions, you could do:

```
condition = (y>0.0) & (x-y > -Q1)
valid_x = np.extract(condition, x)
valid_y = np.extract(condition, y)
print(valid_x, valid_y)
# [  5.  10.  15.  20.] [  5.  10.  15.  20.]
```

Answer (score 0):

straight forward would be something like (pseudo code):

```
for element in array:
    if element > 0:
```