# Q2: AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'size'

Tags: arrays, numpy, boolean, compare, logical-operators

> ```
> Could anyone tell me why I'm getting the error type: AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute
> ```
>
> 'size' in like 57?
>       for this synthax: `out=np.zeros((x.size,y.size))`

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from numpy import exp,sqrt,pi
from sympy import Integral, log, exp, sqrt, pi
import math
from numpy import array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import scipy.integrate
from scipy.special import erf
from scipy.stats import norm, gaussian_kde
from quantecon import LAE
from sympy.abc import q
#from sympy import symbols
#var('q')
#q= symbols('q')

## == Define parameters == #
mu=80
sigma=20
b=0.2
Q=80
Q1=Q*(1-b)
Q2=Q*(1+b)
d = (sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))
phi = norm()
n = 500

#Phi(z) = 1/2[1 + erf(z/sqrt(2))].

def p_k_positive(x, y):
   # x, y = np.array(x, dtype=float), np.array(y, dtype=float)
    Positive_RG = norm.pdf(x[:, None] - y[None, :]+Q1, mu, sigma)
    print('Positive_R = ', Positive_RG)
    return Positive_RG 

def p_k_negative(x, y):
   # x, y = np.array(x, dtype=float), np.array(y, dtype=float)
    Negative_RG = norm.pdf(x[:, None] - y[None, :]+Q2, mu, sigma) 
    print('Negative_RG = ', Negative_RG)
    return Negative_RG 

def p_k_zero(x, y):
   # x, y = np.array(x, dtype=float), np.array(y, dtype=float)
    Zero_RG = (1/(2*math.sqrt(2*math.pi)))*(erf((x[:, None]+Q2-mu)/(sigma*math.sqrt(2)))-erf((x[:, None]+Q1-mu)/(sigma*math.sqrt(2))))
    #Zero_RG =norm.pdf
    print('Zero_RG',Zero_RG)
    return Zero_RG

def myFilter(x,y):
    x, y = x.squeeze, y.squeeze
    out=np.zeros((x.size,y.size))
    xyDiff = x[:, None] - y[None, :]
    out=np.where(np.bitwise_and(y[None, :] > 0.0, xyDiff >= -Q1), p_k_positive(x, y), out) # unless the sum functions are different
    out=np.where(np.bitwise_and(y[None, :] < 0.0, x[:, None] >= -Q1), p_k_negative(x, y), out)
    out=np.where(np.bitwise_and(y[None, :] ==0.0, xyDiff >= -Q1), p_k_zero(x, y), out)
    return out


Z = phi.rvs(n)
X = np.empty(n)
for t in range(n-1):
    X[t+1] = X[t] + Z[t]
    #X[t+1] = np.abs(X[t]) + Z[t]
psi_est = LAE(myFilter, X)
k_est = gaussian_kde(X)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7))
ys = np.linspace(-200.0, 200.0, 200)
ax.plot(ys, psi_est(ys), 'g-', lw=2, alpha=0.6, label='look ahead estimate')
ax.plot(ys, k_est(ys), 'k-', lw=2, alpha=0.6, label='kernel based estimate')
ax.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You're still not calling `myFilter`, as you haven't given it any arguments.  You're passing the whole function to `LAE` and unless that's expected -  who knows what it's doing.

Comment: The look ahead estimator is a class from quentecon. It is only expecting (p,X) as constructed unles I undertood it wrongly. Here's the class and what is doing inside in few lines. http://quanteconpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/quantecon/lae.html#LAE. here p=`myFilter'

Comment: where does `phi.rvs` come from?  What is its output?

Comment: I messed up.  it should be  `x, y = x.squeeze(), y.squeeze()`

Comment: first, many thanks @DanielForsman for your continuing help. my code is an adaptation of the code provided here and the results in exercise 1 of this link http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/QuantEcon/QuantEcon.applications/blob/master/stationary_densities. except that I have a piecewise function that I am dealing with /statd_solutions_py.ipynb .... phi = norm() and object .rvs is used for continuous random variables in python .

Comment: @DanielForsman ahhhhhhhhhhh it works!!!!!!!!!!!! you are a legend sir!!!!!!

Comment: @DanielF F could you possibly help me with this Question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209765/code-not-executing-while-loop-and-for-loop-properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x, y = x.squeeze, y.squeeze`

Should be

`x, y = x.squeeze(), y.squeeze()`

or you're trying to take the `size` of a function.